# About dynamic memory in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

This is the program I wrote in response to an exercise in *C++ Primer*. I don't know why it prints the last number in the vector twice.

```
vector<int>* create_dyn_vec() {
    return new vector<int>();
}
void give_value(vector<int>* ivec_ptr, istream& in) {
    int i;
    while (in) {

        in >> i;
        ivec_ptr->push_back(i);
    }
}
void print(vector<int>* ivec_ptr) {
    for (auto& i : *ivec_ptr)
        cout << i << " " << endl;
}

int main() {
    auto ivec_dyn_ptr=create_dyn_vec();
    give_value(ivec_dyn_ptr, cin);
    print(ivec_dyn_ptr);
    delete ivec_dyn_ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your immediate problem of duplicated last number, replace

```
while (in) {
    in >> i;
```

with just

```
while( in >> i ) {
```

The original code doesn't check whether the input operation succeeds, before it appends the number to the vector. Thus at the end of the file, where the input operation fails, the number is unchanged, and is appended.

In the replacement code the expression `in >> i` attempts the input operation and produces a reference to the stream as its *expression result*. The reference is used as the `while` *condition*, and when used as a *condition* it's converted to `bool`. That conversion is defined by the stream as producing `not in.fail()`, where `fail` is the member function that tells you whether the last i/o operation on this stream failed or succeded.

---

Tip: Instead of passing pointers around you can use C++ *references*.

---

With more idiomatic C++ this code would be like …

```
void load_from( istream& in, vector<int>& v )
{
    int i;
    while( in >> i )
    {
        v.push_back( i );
    }
}

void print( vector<int> const& v )
{
    for( auto const& i : v )
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    load_from( cin, v );
    print( v );
}
```

Note that there are no `new` or `delete` expressions here. Much of the point of using collection classes like `vector` is that it *automates memory management*. Adding manual memory management on top rather defeats the purpose.

Disclaimer: I've not tried to compile the code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I just did it as required by the question. It's an exercise to use manage dynamic memory.

Answer (score 3):

Because the end of the file condition on a `std::istream` is set ***after*** you attempt to read from it, not before:

```
while (in) {

    in >> i;
    ivec_ptr->push_back(i);
}
```

After you've read the last value in the file, you restart the while loop again:

```
while (in) {
```

This evaluates to `true`, because the end of the file condition has not been reached yet.

```
    in >> i;
    ivec_ptr->push_back(i);
```

You then attempt to read the next value. This attempt fails, and sets the end of file condition on the `std::istream`. But you `push_back()` the value to the vector nevertheless. This happens to be the last value you've read in the file, effectively appending it a 2nd time, to the vector.

On the next iteration, the end of the file condition terminates the `while` loop.

Comment: Might be worth it to explain how to fix it (i.e. while (in >> in)) and why that works.